# Show user Logged in details in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am Currently developing small application and i want show the current  logged in Details `(ex.name , email id , phone number, and password)`.

**My question is :-**

In my ViewController i have a few buttons i.e : **Login , Register , Settings and About** .
If user not log in  Setting Button should be disable or inactive and it should  alert  **"please login to view details"**  if user logged in ,it should display the his registered details such as **name,email, phone no and password** 
How can i do this ? can any one help me out of this ?

**Here is my code :**

**LoginViewController.M**

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize userName;
@synthesize passWord;
@synthesize forgotEmailID;
@synthesize topStrip;
@synthesize backBtIB;
@synthesize loginBtIB;
@synthesize forgetBtIB;
@synthesize bgViewIB;
@synthesize loginTittle;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    forgotEmailID.hidden=YES;
    [userName setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];
    [passWord setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:bgViewIB];

}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    userName.layer.cornerRadius=10.0f;
    userName.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    userName.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    userName.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
    passWord.layer.cornerRadius=10.0f;
    passWord.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    passWord.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    passWord.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;

}



- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"email:%@",userName.text);
    NSLog(@"password:%@",passWord.text);

    if([userName.text isEqualToString:@""] || [passWord.text isEqualToString:@""])

    {
        UIAlertView* alertViewq = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please enter all the details." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertViewq show];

    }

    else
    {
        NSString *getdetails = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&email=%@&password=%@",userName.text,passWord.text];
        NSLog(@"get:%@",getdetails);
        NSData *getData = [getdetails dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[getData length]];


        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/login.php"]]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:getData];
        NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if (theConnection)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"Check your networking configuration." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }

        ViewController *NVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];
        [self presentViewController:NVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


}

#pragma mark - MFMessage Delegate

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent)
    {
        NSLog(@"\n\n Email Sent");
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (IBAction)forgetPasswordButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"email:%@",forgotEmailID.text);

    if([forgotEmailID.text isEqualToString:@""])

       {
           UIAlertView* alertViewq = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Request Forgot Password" message:@"Please enter your Register e-mail ." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          alertViewq.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
           [alertViewq show];

}

      }
@end
```

**SettingVC.m**

```
#import "SettingVC.h"

@interface SettingVC ()

@end

@implementation SettingVC
@synthesize emailField;
@synthesize nameField;
@synthesize phoneField;
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize passwordField;
@synthesize confirmPassField;

@synthesize bgView;
@synthesize topStrip;
@synthesize setingTittle;
@synthesize backBtIB;
@synthesize imageView1;
@synthesize nameLbl;
@synthesize emailLbl;
@synthesize phoneLbl;
@synthesize imageView2;
@synthesize passwordLbl;
@synthesize confirmpassLbl;
@synthesize infoTextView;
@synthesize imageView3;
@synthesize switchView;
@synthesize saveDetailsLbl;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appdelegate=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appdelegate.ifLogin = YES;

    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:bgView];



    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView* view in scrollView.subviews)
    {
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
    }
      [scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(305, 1100))];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




- (IBAction)BackButton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)SaveButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"name:%@",nameField.text);
    NSLog(@"email:%@",emailField.text);
    NSLog(@"phoneno:%@",phoneField.text);
    NSLog(@"password:%@",passwordField.text);

    /* if ([self isValidEmail:[emailTextField text]] == 1) {

     UIAlertView* alertViewq = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please enter Valid email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alertViewq show];
     } */

    if([nameField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [emailField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [phoneField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [passwordField.text isEqualToString:@""])

    {

    }

    else
    {
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&name=%@&email=%@&phoneno=%@&password=%@",nameField.text,emailField.text,phoneField.text,passwordField.text];
        NSLog(@"post:%@",post);
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];


        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/Settings.php"]]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if (theConnection)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"Check your networking configuration." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }

}

- (IBAction)LagoutButton:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Comment: when you get the response of user detail store it in Userdefaults and set rootcontroller in  appdelegate by checking userdefaults have data or not...user default have data go to other page otherwise go to login

Comment: can you attach your project here I fix your issue

Comment: ok thank you , can you provide any sample code or reference links  please